# how to make a dvd which can be played in a dvd player

Tags: video, dvd

Is there any application in which is programmed to make dvds which can be played in a dvd player

i recently saw a dvd in which all the videos were present in .VOB format so do i need any extra plugins to convert it into mp4 format and are mp4 formats complatible with DVD players

if any one thinks this question does'nt suits this site then i recommend them to migrate this question to that site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using 'DeVeDe DVD/CD Video Creator'. This application allows to create video CDs and DVDs, suitable to be reproduced in home DVD players. For some details see Ubuntu Software Center.